# Could not create MokListRT Volume full Boot impossible

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, moklistrt

I upgraded yesterday to ubuntu 23.10 (from immediately preceding version)

Upgrade normal with no reported errors via terminal.
Restart immediately after upgrade normal in version 23.10

Just after restart, report that 2 items needed addtional update; one was snap and I cannot remember the second one. Launched update which gave error message (something like snap in use....).
The next restart blocked completely the system now unusable.....

error messages as follows

Could not create MokListRT: Volume full
Could not create MokListXRT: Volume full
Could not create SbatlevelRT: Volume full
Could not create MokListTrustedRT: Volume full
Something has gone seriously wrong: import_mok_state() failed : volume full

laptop powers off immediatetly after showing these messages......

I tried to use a bootable usb key containing ubuntu last LTS with no success (same error messages) after having modified boot sequence in bios accordingly.

I also tried to point to EFI BOOTX64.EFI with same result ....

Would it be a GRUB problem ?

Any suggestion to solve this would be welcome....

Laptop ASUS
Processor I7
RAM 16Gb
c: disk formatted by previous version of ubuntu SSD 128Gb with virtually no data
d: disk 1T

Thanks for your cooperation

Comment: Tried various boot seqences (\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi etc...) without any result

Answer (score 1):

I could solve it by deleting the "Forbidden signatures"

[image]

[image]

Comment: My hero! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by setting *Default settings* or *Factory settings*.
The `.mok` files are part of the EFI shell; it may be that a combination of Windows booting and Ubuntu grub produced this problem...