Install Ubuntu 24.04 on PC without operating system and new blank SSD
Install Ubuntu 24.04 on PC without operating system on a blank SSD. Error message is Could not create MokListRT:  Volume Full or according to other posts there is no EFI partition on the blank SSD. I installed 22.04 on 3 other desktops last year with no problems, but the EFI problem has been ongoing for years with many other computers.

what is your question?  ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

I believe you may find your answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1491615/could-not-create-moklistrt-volume-full-boot-impossible Having to do with Secure Boot in the EFI perhaps??

I found the answer and it's too complicated to explain here, but it has to do with  several issues that can fix the problem which is caused by Microsoft and other misleading Internet posts.  I never did find one source that explained all the steps required to prepare a used SSD for installing a new operating system and getting the BIOS correct.  Next time I will spend more time searching for a complete solution source, so other people won't have to post so many, I tried this and this and nothing worked.

Another factor is that manufacturers keep making changes without any thought about the secondary effects that affect older PCs because they are only interested in selling new systems in the near future.  There is no doubt that AI makes this type of problem far worse than it would be without AI giving misleading and incorrect data and filling up all the space even on large monitors, which makes it almost impossible to read with such rapid responses.
